# Reverse to im2java in Matlab?

Tags: java, image, matlab

How to convert java Image to Matlab image? Is there any function, reversing `im2java`?

Suppose I have a script:

```
jimage=javaObjectEDT('java.awt.image.BufferedImage',800,600,java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
jgraphics=jimage.createGraphics;
jgraphics.drawString('Hello World',0,0)
```

How to take what was drawn back to matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [mathworks support](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-2WPAYR/), there is no inbuilt function to do this, but you can extract the pixel data from the java Image and return that as a matrix to matlab. Example code is given in the link provided.